# Variable change in the Switch statement but doesn't reflect in the rest of the code

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and I'm writing a Rock, Paper & Scissors game for my C++ class. In the algorithm, I'm told to do the following:

> Using a switch statement, change the random number (1-3) to ‘R’, ‘P’, and ‘S’ in computerChoice

Now, that I have done so, the variable `computerChoice` that is in the `switch` statement is not being used in the `if` statement.

What am I doing wrong here?

Here's my code:

```
/*
This program is a game of rock, paper and scissors.
*/

#include<iostream> // required for cin, cout
#include<ctime>     // required for time
#include<cstdlib>  // required for srand(), rand()

using namespace std; 

int main() // main function

{

        srand(time(0)); // seed (number will appear once)


        // declaring variables as characters
        char userChoice;

        // prompt the user toar  enter R for rock, S for scissors or P for paper
        cout << "Enter R for rock, S for scissors or P for paper." << endl;
        cin >> userChoice;

        int computerChoice = rand()%3; // to generate a number between 0 and 2 

        cout << "The computer chose the number " << computerChoice << endl;

        // convert 0 to R, 1 to S and 2 to P
        switch(computerChoice) 
        {

            case 0:
                computerChoice = 'R'; // convert 0 to Rock
                cout << "Computer chose Rock. " << endl; // print rock as computer's choice
                break;

            case 1:
                computerChoice = 'S'; // convert 1 to Scissors
                cout << "Computer chose Scissors. " << endl; // print scissors as computer's choice
                break;

            case 2:
                computerChoice = 'P'; // convert 2 to Paper
                cout << "Computer chose Paper. " << endl; // print paper as computer 's choice
                break;
        }


        // Determine the victor
        if (computerChoice == userChoice) { // Computer's choice is equal to User's Choice
            cout << "It's a tie. " << endl;
        }

        else if (computerChoice == 'R') { // Computer chose Rock

            if (userChoice == 'P') {// User chose Paper
            cout << "User wins - paper covers rock" << endl;
            }
            else {// User chose Scissors
            cout << "Computer wins - rock crushes scissors" << endl;
            }
        }
        else if (computerChoice == 'S') { // Computer chose Scissors

            if (userChoice == 'R') { // User chose Rock
            cout << "Computer wins - rock crushes scissors" << endl;
            }
            else { // User chose Paper
            cout << "Computer wins - scissors cuts paper" << endl;
            }
        }

        else //computer chose Paper
            {

            if (userChoice == 'R') { // User chose Rock
            cout << "Computer wins - paper covers rock" << endl;
            }
            else { // User chose Scissors
            cout << "User wins - scissors cuts paper" << endl;
            }
        }   

    return (0); //Stop program
} // Close Main function
```

Comment: Why do you think userchoice should be `char` and computerchoice be `int`?

Comment: Your program looks fine to me. It also runs fine in my environment. What makes you think there is a problem?

Comment: @RSahu While my answer may be wrong, or at least fail to explain the OP, it is generally bad practice to mix `char` and `int` in this way.  These types may not have the same number of bits, and I can forsee a problem with doing that.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it's fine because you're assigning the same range of values to both variables. The `char` widens to the size of an `int` for comparison.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I agree with you. I would have used `char choices[3] = {'R', 'P', 'S'};` and used `choices[computerChoice]` instead of what the OP is using.

Comment: @RSahu Thank you for the insight! I'm running this code in DevC++. This is the program my instructor told us to use. Is this why I'm not getting the correct output?

Comment: @dev_P, I don't see any problem with your program. You still haven't explained why you think there is a problem.

Comment: @RSahu I apologize. It's working now. I assume that I had to restart DevC++, compile and rerun again the program before I posted this question and code. I did learn this "char choices[3] = {'R', 'P', 'S'}; and used choices[computerChoice]" from your comment. Thank you once again.

Comment: @dev_P, you are welcome. Please delete the post. It's unlikely to be useful to  anybody else.